Telerik UI WPF - How Can I Add a DocumentVariableField to a Table Cell Programmatically
We are using Telerik UI for WPF and are creating a table which then gets inserted into a RadRichTextBox. We need to add a DocumentVariableField to one of the cells, can anyone please advise.
        public void AddAddress()
        {
            string addrName = " ";
            string[] rowName = new string[] { "Job Title", "Employer", "Address", "Tel.", "Tel. Dir.", "Mobile", "Email", "Website", "Fax", "Details", "Address", "Tel.", "Mobile", "Email", "Details" };
            if(_selelement != null)
            {
                addrName = _selelement.GetAttribute("title");
            }
            RadDocument document = new RadDocument();
            Section section = new Section();

            TableWidthUnit w1 = new TableWidthUnit(100);
            TableWidthUnit w2 = new TableWidthUnit(520);

            Table table = new Table();
            table.StyleName = RadDocumentDefaultStyles.DefaultTableGridStyleName;

            TableRow row1 = new TableRow();
            TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
            cell1.Background = Color.FromRgb(174, 255, 190);
            cell1.PreferredWidth = w1;
            cell1.Padding = new Telerik.Windows.Documents.Layout.Padding(3, 6, 3, 6);
            Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
            Span s1 = new Span();
            s1.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            s1.FontFamily = new FontFamily(CGlobals.docu_default_font);
            s1.FontSize = Unit.PointToDip(CGlobals.docu_default_font_size);
            s1.Text = "Name";
            p1.Inlines.Add(s1);
            cell1.Blocks.Add(p1);
            row1.Cells.Add(cell1);

            TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
            cell2.Background = Color.FromRgb(174, 255, 190);
            cell2.PreferredWidth = w2;
            cell2.Padding = new Telerik.Windows.Documents.Layout.Padding(3, 6, 3, 6);
            Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph();
            Span s2 = new Span();
            s2.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            s2.FontFamily = new FontFamily(CGlobals.docu_default_font);
            s2.FontSize = Unit.PointToDip(CGlobals.docu_default_font_size);
            s2.Text = addrName;  // This needs to contain the DocumentVariable
            p2.Inlines.Add(s2);
            cell2.Blocks.Add(p2);
            row1.Cells.Add(cell2);
            table.Rows.Add(row1);

            int rowCount = 0;
            foreach(string rname in rowName)
            {
                rowCount++;
                row1 = new TableRow();
                cell1 = new TableCell();
                p1 = new Paragraph();
                if (rowCount < 11)
                {
                    cell1.Background = Color.FromRgb(255, 229, 153);
                    p1.Background = Color.FromRgb(255, 229, 153);
                }
                else
                {
                    cell1.Background = Color.FromRgb(196, 255, 255);
                    p1.Background = Color.FromRgb(196, 255, 255);
                }
                cell1.Padding = new Telerik.Windows.Documents.Layout.Padding(3, 6, 3, 6);
                s1 = new Span();
                s1.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                s1.FontFamily = new FontFamily(CGlobals.docu_default_font);
                s1.FontSize = Unit.PointToDip(CGlobals.docu_default_font_size);
                s1.Text = rname;
                p1.Inlines.Add(s1);
                cell1.Blocks.Add(p1);
                row1.Cells.Add(cell1);

                cell2 = new TableCell();
                cell2.Background = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255);
                cell2.Padding = new Telerik.Windows.Documents.Layout.Padding(3, 6, 3, 6);
                p2 = new Paragraph();
                s2 = new Span();
                s2.FontFamily = new FontFamily(CGlobals.docu_default_font);
                s2.FontSize = Unit.PointToDip(CGlobals.docu_default_font_size);
                s2.Text = " ";
                p2.Inlines.Add(s2);
                cell2.Blocks.Add(p2);
                row1.Cells.Add(cell2);
                table.Rows.Add(row1);
            }

            section.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph());
            section.Blocks.Add(table);
            section.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph());
            document.Sections.Add(section);

            doc_text.Document = document;

            // Add a DocumentVariable and assign the value to it
            // This needs to be changed so the variable can be added to Row 1, Cell 2 in the table created above
            doc_text.Document.DocumentVariables.Add("1001", addrName);
            DocumentVariableField docVariable = new DocumentVariableField() { VariableName = "1001"  };
           
            doc_text.InsertField(docVariable, FieldDisplayMode.Result);

//            ChangeAddress(addrName);
        }

A variable needs to be used so it can be updated when another field in the UI is amended.

In the above code, the DocumentVariableField is added to the document and we are able to update by:
public void ChangeAddress(string address)
{
    doc_text.Document.DocumentVariables["1001"] = address;
    var field = doc_text.Document.EnumerateChildrenOfType<FieldRangeStart>().Where(x => x.Field.FieldTypeName == "DOCVARIABLE"
    && ((DocumentVariableField)x.Field).VariableName == "1001").FirstOrDefault();

    if (field != null)
    {
        doc_text.UpdateField(field);
    }
}

I have tried using Tags but they do not persist when the contents of the RadRichTextBox are saved to an RTF.
Thank you

The good people at Telerik, came back to me with a solution.
They advised using the RadDocumentEditor:
    // Code Supplied by Telerik
    RadDocumentEditor editor = new RadDocumentEditor(document);
    var cell = document.EnumerateChildrenOfType<TableCell>().ToList()[1];

    if (cell != null)
    {
        DocumentPosition position = new DocumentPosition(document);
        position.MoveToDocumentElementStart(cell.Blocks.First());
        document.CaretPosition.MoveToPosition(position);
        DocumentVariableField docVariable = new DocumentVariableField() { VariableName = "1001" };
        editor.InsertField(docVariable);
    }
    doc_text.Document = document;

    // Add a DocumentVariable and assign the value to it
    // This needs to be changed so the variable can be added to Row 1, Cell 2 in the table created above
    //doc_text.Document.DocumentVariables.Add("1001", addrName);

    ChangeAddress(addrName);

